# What R packages do you find most useful in your daily work?

Tags: r

**Duplicate thread:** [I just installed the latest version of R. What packages should I obtain?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1676/i-just-installed-the-latest-version-of-r-what-packages-should-i-obtain)

What are the [R](http://www.r-project.org/) packages you couldn't imagine your daily work with data?
Please list both general and specific tools.

UPDATE:
As for 24.10.10 `ggplot2` seems to be the winer with 7 votes.

Other packages mentioned more than one are:

- `plyr` - 4
- `RODBC`, `RMySQL` - 4
- `sqldf` - 3
- `lattice` - 2
- `zoo` - 2
- `Hmisc/rms` - 2
- `Rcurl` - 2
- `XML` - 2

Thanks all for your answers!

Comment: Very subjective question: this question cannot be answered, and is not suitable for a QA site.

Comment: Should probably be community wiki; useful question here but doesn't have definitive answer.

Comment: @Shane: good point. moved.
@ Egon: subjective indeed. but if the answers come from knowledgeable people i don't mind dose of subjectivity.
i've started learning R quite recently and have couple of dozens installed to explore, however i notice that there are tools that I use much more often irrespectively of the task at hand.

Comment: It would be interesting if StackExchange could support some method of linking community wiki posts across sites.  Because I will bet this question has been asked on Stackoverflow and I also think that Statistical Analysis may attract some people that wouldn't usually visit SO.

Comment: @Sharpie: there have been several interesting SO posts like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295955/what-is-the-most-useful-r-trick or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535021/whats-the-biggest-r-gotcha-youve-run-across however they are not focused on packages. and i agree, linkage of community wiki could be really useful.

Comment: This one's _definitely_ for SO!

Comment: I disagree that it's for SO, especially considering the discussions on meta that supporting tools for statistical analysis (including software) is on-topic....

Comment: I vote to close because "his question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see link:
TOP 100 R PACKAGES FOR 2013 (JAN-MAY)
http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/06/top-100-r-packages-for-2013-jan-may/

Answer (score 23):

I use [**plyr**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html) and [**ggplot2**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html) the most on a daily basis.

I also rely heavily on time series packages; most especially, the [**zoo**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) package.

Answer (score 12):

In a narrow sense, R Core has a recommendation: the "recommended" packages.

Everything else depends on your data analysis tasks at hand, and I'd recommend the [Task Views](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views) at CRAN.

Comment: +1 Package demands heavily depend on each individual and I think Task Views are the way to start anyone.

Answer (score 8):

I use the **[xtable](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/index.html)** package. The xtable package turns tables produced by R (in particular, the tables displaying the anova results) into LaTeX tables, to be included in an article.

Answer (score 8):

[multicore](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multicore/index.html) is quite nice for tool for making faster scripts faster.
[cacheSweave](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cacheSweave/index.html) saves a lot of time when using `Sweave`.

Answer (score 8):

**ggplot2** - hands down best visualization for R.

**RMySQL/RSQLite/RODBC** - for connecting to a databases

**sqldf** - manipulate data.frames with SQL queries

**Hmisc/rms** - packages from Frank Harrell containing convenient miscellaneous functions and nice functions for regression analyses.

**GenABEL** - nice package for genome-wide association studies

**Rcmdr** - a decent GUI for R if you need one.

Also check out [CRANtastic - this link](http://crantastic.org/popcon) has a list of the most popular R packages. Many on the top of the list have already been ment

Answer (score 8):

data.table is my favorite now! Very look forward to the new version with the more wishlist implemented.

Answer (score 6):

For me personally, I use the following three packages the most, all available from the awesome [Omega Project for Statistical Computing](http://www.omegahat.org) (I do not claim to be an expert, but for my purposes they are very easy to use):

- **RCurl**: It has lots of options which allows access to websites that the default functions in base R would have difficulty with I think it's fair to say. It is an R-interface to the libcurl library, which has the *added* benefit of a whole community outside of R developing it. Also available on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html).
- **XML**: It is very forgiving of parsing malformed XML/HTML. It is an R-interface to the libxml2 library and again has the *added* benefit of a whole community outside of R developing it Also available on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html).
- **RJSONIO**: It allows one to parse the text returned from a json call and organise it into a list structure for further analysis.The competitor to this package is rjson but this one has the advantage of being vectorised, readily extensible through S3/S4, fast and scalable to large data.

Answer (score 6):

Packages I often use are [raster](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html), [sp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/index.html), [spatstat](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/index.html), [vegan](http://cran.r-project.org/package=vegan) and [splancs](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splancs/index.html). I sometimes use ggplot2, tcltk and lattice.

Answer (score 6):

**Sweave** lets you embed R code in a LaTeX document.  The results of executing the code, and optionally the source code, become part of the final document.

So instead of, for example, pasting an image produced by R into a LaTeX file, you can paste the R *code* into the file and keep everything in one place.

Comment: Just a hint for all those who want to get started on reproducible research with R. I would advice you to have a look at the newish package `knitr` instead of Sweave. It's basically Sweave on steroids. It is as easy, if not easier, to learn and far more flexible.

Answer (score 6):

I imagine graphics and data manipulation are two things that are useful no matter what you are doing. Thus, I'd recommend:

- ggplot2 (great graphics)
- lattice (great graphics)
- plyr (useful for data manipulation)
- Hmisc (good for descriptive statistics and much more)

Answer (score 4):

Day-to-day the most useful package must be "foreign" which has functions for reading and writing data for other statistical packages e.g. Stata, SPSS, Minitab, SAS, etc. Working in a field where R is not that commonplace means that this is a very important package.

Answer (score 4):

zoo and xts are a must in my work!

Answer (score 4):

I find [lattice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/index.html) along with the companion book "Lattice: Multivariate Data Visualization with R" by Deepayan Sarkar invaluable.

Answer (score 4):

You can get user reviews of packages on [crantastic](http://crantastic.org/reviews)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using some of the packages provided by [revolution R](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/). In particular, I quite like the:

- [multicore](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multicore/index.html) package for parallel computing using shared memory processors
- there optimized packages for [matrices](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/why-revolution-r/benchmarks.php)

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing any kind of predictive modeling, [caret](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) is a godsend.  Especially combined with the [multicore](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multicore/index.html) package, some pretty amazing things are possible.

Answer (score 3):

I use

car, doBy, Epi, ggplot2, gregmisc (gdata, gmodels, gplots, gtools), Hmisc, plyr, RCurl, RDCOMClient, reshape, RODBC, TeachingDemos, XML.

a lot.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a question that doesn't have "an answer".  It is completely dependent on what you want to do.  That aside, I'll share the packages that I install as a standard with an R update...

```
install.packages(c("car","gregmisc","xtable","Design","Hmisc","psych",
                        "CCA", "fda", "zoo", "fields",
                      "catspec","sem","multilevel","Deducer","RQDA"))
```

and leave it to you to investigate those packages and see if they are valuable to you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with Latex, I recommend **TikZ Device** for outputting nice, Latex-formatted (like PSTricks) graphics. The output you get is text-based Latex code, which can be embedded with include(filename) into any figure environment.

Pros:

- Same font in graphics as in your text
- Professional look

Cons:

- Takes longer to compile than PNG or PDF
- for very complex R graphics, there are could be some display errors

https://github.com/Sharpie/RTikZDevice - Project, Packages available from CRAN and R-Forge

Comment: No disrespect, but that strikes me as entirely subjective. I have used latex for since the late 80s and R since the 90s yet I see no good reason to move away from embedding eps files. Everybody's mileage will differ here, and Thomas should maybe look at Task Views for particular problem domains.

Comment: @Dirk: Good typography should not draw attention to its self and getting different text from LaTeX and R graphics [is very visible](http://i.imgur.com/4MLQq.png) (EPS output on the left, [Sweave source code](https://gist.github.com/965459)). Admittingly the example is a bit biased as no effort is made to customize the font used by `eps`. The point is that `tikz`  should match the LaTeX document font, font size, letterspacing, kerning, ligaturing, etc. *by default*. If it doesn't, I consider it a bug.

Answer (score 3):

You can also take a look at [Task views](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/) on CRAN and see if something suit your needs. I agree with @Jeromy for these must-have packages (for data manipulation and plotting).

Answer (score 3):

I use `lattice`, `ggplot2`, `lubridate`, `reshape`, `boot`, `e1071`, `car`, `forecast`, and `zoo` a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I could not live without:

- **lattice** for graphics
- **xlsx** or **XLConnect** for reading Excel files
- **rtf** to create reports in rtf format (I would prefer **Sword** or **R2wd** but I cannot install statconn at work; I will surely try **odfWeave** soon.)
- **nlme** and **lme4** for mixed models
- **ff** for working with large arrays

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend the new shiny based packages to everyone, it makes data visualisation and inspection interactive and thus easier than writing code in R espacially in the beginning.

A good example would be **ggplotgui**

Answer (score 2):

We mostly use:

- ggplot - for charts
- stats
- e1071 - for [SVMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine)

Comment: You may also want to check out kernlab and caret for SVMs.  They're interesting (thought not necessarily better) alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

I work with both R and [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) and I use [R.matlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/index.html) a lot to transfer data between the two.

Answer (score 2):

**RODBC** for accessing data from databases, **sqldf** for performing simple SQL queries on dataframes (although I am forcing myself to use native R commands), and **ggplot2** and **plyr**

Answer (score 2):

Jeromy mentioned my first pick: Lattice.

I also have found the `doBy` package and its `summaryBy` function to be insanely useful. They extend `aggregate` with a formula syntax that lets you aggregate multiple functions simultaneously in non-trivial ways.  Great if you want, say, mean, std. dev., and length.

Answer (score 2):

lattice, car, MASS, foreign, party.

Answer (score 2):

For me 
I am using **kernlab** for Kernel-based Machine Learning Lab and **e1071** for SVM and **ggplot2** for graphics

Answer (score 2):

I use 
ggplot2, vegan and reshape quite often.

Answer (score 2):

I like **roxygen** for its Curry() function.

Answer (score 2):

**RColorBrewer** has not been mentioned here, I use it often for plotting if I need color schemes

Answer (score 2):

I am a big fan of RCPP when I need a rapid for loop or to perform non very R compliant treatments. It is very well implemented in the R eco system, can receive Matrix / sparse Matrix without conversion as arguments in a function.

C++ syntax is easy when you are doing simple stuff (which is often my case).

Really, you don't need to be a package maker to need this awesome lib.

Did I say C++ is very rapid?

Answer (score 2):

The [doParallel](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/index.html) and [foreach](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html) packages have made my life so much easier by allowing me to parallelize my code and run it on a compute-optimized instance on [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)! I use them very often. But that would not have been possible without the [RStudio AMIs](http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/) released by Louis Aslett. Finally, I have to mention the [stringr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) package which really makes working with strings a walk in the park. Use it in every text mining application. And I also use [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) very frequently to produce high quality reports of my work. Many thanks for this amazing package Yihui Xie!

Answer (score 1):

Some packages are very useful in R.

I will just recommand **kernlab** for Kernel-based Machine Learning Lab and **e1071** for SVM and **ggplot2** for graphics

Answer (score 1):

I use ggplot2, reshape, lattice, knitr more often.