# I just installed the latest version of R. What packages should I obtain?

Tags: r

**Duplicate thread:** [What R packages do you find most useful in your daily work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73/what-r-packages-do-you-find-most-useful-in-your-daily-work)

Are there any R packages that are just plain good to have, regardless of the type of work you are doing? If so, what are these packages? If not, what packages do you find the most useful?

Comment: Making community wiki, and this is a really close duplicate of the other. Is the searching acting up? I searched for "r packages" with and without quotes and didn't see that...I wonder if it had something to do with the downtime last night.

Comment: While not being moderator, I would vote to close as a duplicate; we don't need more than one R package feed.

Comment: I would close as a duplicate; also this question is within the scope of the site.