# What is your favorite, easy to use statistical analysis website or software package?

Tags: software

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some valuable Statistical Analysis open source projects?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-are-some-valuable-statistical-analysis-open-source-projects)

I understand the basics of statistical analysis, but I am not good at math.  What is the best website or software package (preferably FOSS) that can analysize the data, find correlations, levels of confidence, etc. automagically/with a great UI?

Comment: Your question is great, unfortunately it's very similar to a previous (very highly rated) [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3). Perhaps you could change your question to just ask about websites?

Comment: @csgillespie Oh yes, I forgot about this one, sorry!

Answer (score 5):

Your objectives seem rather vague, but I think the open-source [R statistical package](http://www.R-project.org/) should fit your needs, and beyond. Although primarily a command line driven software, you will find several useful GUIs, e.g. [Rcommander](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/Rcmdr/) or [deducer](http://www.deducer.org/) to help you start with.

The [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/) website contains everything you need to start with R, including a lot of [official](http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html) and [contributed](http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html) documentation.

R is made of several additional packages (a kind of extensions to the core statistical functions), and you will find interesting pointers on these related questions: [What R packages do you find most useful in your daily work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73/what-r-packages-do-you-find-most-useful-in-your-daily-work), [I just installed the latest version of R. What packages should I obtain?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1676/i-just-installed-the-latest-version-of-r-what-packages-should-i-obtain).

Answer (score 1):

[RapidMiner](http://rapidminer.com/) is a nice GUI based, workflow data mining tool. It's open source and runs on mac, linux, windows.

I think R and RapidMiner will end up as the predominant tools, with R being for people that like command-line style linux-like work, and RapidMiner for Windows and Mac types that prefer GUI based work.